# Doorkeeper::AuthorizationsController#create Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, doorkeeper

I followed the page https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-flow by testing the API

```
curl -F grant_type=password \
-F username=foo@bar.com \
-F password=mypass \
-X POST http://localhost:3000/oauth/token
```

And I got the response:

> {"access_token":"6d4398b75d94835631a453af770161a6f58618b101b58ccf62a5a8492bce3440","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":600,"refresh_token":"c1445d0a27a8278268c1187c2e3da7163525f1fac8093890430edd328f51c3de","created_at":1429931390}

But when I call /oauth/authorize with:

`curl -F response_type=6d4398b75d94835631a453af770161a6f58618b101b58ccf62a5a8492bce3440 \
-F client_id=9c291dc4aa87bfafd6c6a4cf6930d225c106f8fe88e1d0769832047f1ee011c4 \
-F client_secret=decba5aca425095978d33653ef03d654f0b74427bcec0596bdde518016708c35 \
-F redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob \
-F username=foo@bar.com \
-X POST http://localhost:3000/oauth/authorize`

But I got:

> Started POST "/oauth/authorize" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-25 00:30:05 -0300
>   Processing by Doorkeeper::AuthorizationsController#create as */*
>     Parameters: {"response_type"=>"6d4398b75d94835631a453af770161a6f58618b101b58ccf62a5a8492bce3440", "client_id"=>"9c291dc4aa87bfafd6c6a4cf6930d225c106f8fe88e1d0769832047f1ee011c4", "client_secret"=>"[FILTERED]", "redirect_uri"=>"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", "username"=>"foo@bar.com"}
>   Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
>   Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms
>   ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken): 
>   ...

What, am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is expected behavior. The authorization form is rendered as HTML in the provider app, and thankfully Rails by default checks that the CSRF token it renders in the form matches upon form submission. A `curl` command without that token would thus raise "CSRF validation failed".

Comment: I know this, but I'm trying to use doorskeep oauth2 to write an API, and API doesn't have HTML rendered.

Comment: If you understand the risks, you might want to disable Rails forgery protection for that controller action. Doorkeeper doesn't provide an option for this, you will need to reopen that controller.

Comment: better to configure the doorkeeper gem to support the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow (https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/using-resource-owner-password-credentials-flow) in cases you'd like to allow the API client to ask for username&password. The flow you're using is designed to redirect the user to your web service to securely log in and never expose your user's credentials to 3rd party apps.

Comment: @MarcosSousa did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

If you're working on an API only, my guess is that you can simply turned it off in the environment file (test/developpement/production.rb) by adding this line :

`config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false'`

Cheers !

Comment: that's quite a bad idea, the CSRF protection is there for a reason. In this case it's protecting the part of the oauth flow the user is going through with their browser.

Comment: That's why i precised first about the API. Without any browser access, the CSRF protection isn't really usefull.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in the second request you're using a token for `response_type`. It should be, I think, `authorization_code`.

However, from the first response, it looks like it's giving you a bearer token. If so, then to view a protected page (has a before_action: doorkeeper_authorize) the command would be

```
curl http://localhost:3000/protected_page -H "Authorization: Bearer 6d4398b75d94835631a453af770161a6f58618b101b58ccf62a5a8492bce3440"
```

### OAuth2 Library

Do you need to use curl?  I'm having the same failure with the CSRF authenticity token since it thinks it's a form request, but I got it working with the OAuth2 gem.

Register an application (presumably this is protected) at `/oauth/applications`, go to it, click `Authorize`, click `Approve`, and you'll see you've POSTed to a url something like `http://localhost:3000/oauth/authorize?client_id=abc123&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code` with 
the params `"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "state"=>"", "scope"=>"public"` The `abc123` is your one-time-authentication code.

But you still haven't authorized your Application. So, let's get the access_token and refresh_token.

```
client_id = "9c291dc4aa87bfafd6c6a4cf6930d225c106f8fe88e1d0769832047f1ee011c4"
client_secret = "decba5aca425095978d33653ef03d654f0b74427bcec0596bdde518016708c35"
site = "http://localhost:3000"
redirect_uri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
code = "abc123" # see above
ENV['OAUTH_DEBUG'] = 'true'
client = OAuth2::Client.new(client_id, client_secret, :site => site)
token = client.auth_code.get_token(code, redirect_uri: redirect_uri)
access_token = token.token
refresh_token = token.refresh_token
# And if you want:
# if token.expired?
#   new_token = token.refresh!
#   new_token.token
#   new_token.refresh_token
# end
```

If you go to `http://localhost:3000/oauth/authorized_applications` you should see your application is on the list now.

Now, you can view protected pages with something like `curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/protected_page -H "Authorization: Bearer #{access_token}"`

Also see https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/API-endpoint-descriptions-and-examples

Possibly useful info: What Doorkeeper is looking for to validate an auth code

```
redirect_uri.present?
grant = Doorkeeper::AccessGrant.by_token(authorization_code)
grant.redirect_uri == redirect_uri
application = Doorkeeper::Application.by_uid_and_secret(client_id, client_secret)
dk_client = Doorkeeper::OAuth::Client.new(application)
!!dk_client
grant.application_id == dk_client.id
grant.accessible? #  !grant.expired? && !grant.revoked?
```

See

- https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/a70e1a86cf5290dd642e00aedbdbb94bfd553f6b/lib/doorkeeper/oauth/authorization_code_request.rb
- https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/8b59c77ca2324b747ab0570b47f6d14df62fbcc8/spec/support/helpers/url_helper.rb#L50
- https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/8b59c77ca2324b747ab0570b47f6d14df62fbcc8/lib/doorkeeper/models/access_grant_mixin.rb
- https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/blob/0ab3c213f7baa43f232eb18fa46301e1a9460f7d/lib/oauth2/client.rb